# how to extract words following a list of keywords in python using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract locations using Regex in python.
Right now I am doing this:

```
def get_location(s):
    s = s.strip(STRIP_CHARS)
    keywords = "at|outside|near"
    location_pattern = "(?P<location>((?P<place>{keywords}\s[A-Za-z]+)))".format(keywords = keywords)
    location_regex = re.compile(location_pattern, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE | re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE)

    for match in location_regex.finditer(s):
        match_str = match.group(0)
        indices = match.span(0)
        print ("Match", match)
        match_str = match.group(0)
        indices = match.span(0)
        print (match_str)

get_location("Im at building 3")
```

I have three issues:

1. It is only giving "at" as output but it should also give building.
2. `captures = match.capturesdict()` I am not able to use to extract captures where this is working other examples.
3. When I am doing just this `location_pattern = 'at|outside\s\w+`. It seems to be working. Can someone explains what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can post the example of text in which you are searching.

Comment: Could you add to your question a couple of strings and what is the expected outuput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you need to place `{keywords}` inside a non-capturing group: `(?:{keywords})`. Here is a schematic example: `a|b|c\s+\w+` matches either `a` or `b` or `c`+`<whitespace(s)>`+`. When you put the alternation list into a group,`(a|b|c)\s+\w+`, it matches either`a`, or`b`or`c` and only then it tries to match whitespaces and then word chars.

See the updated code (a [demo online](http://rextester.com/WUCCD70911)):

```
import regex as re
def get_location(s):
    STRIP_CHARS = '*'
    s = s.strip(STRIP_CHARS)
    keywords = "at|outside|near"
    location_pattern = "(?P<location>((?P<place>(?:{keywords})\s+[A-Za-z]+)))".format(keywords = keywords)
    location_regex = re.compile(location_pattern, re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)

    for match in location_regex.finditer(s):
        match_str = match.group(0)
        indices = match.span(0)
        print ("Match", match)
        match_str = match.group(0)
        indices = match.span(0)
        print (match_str)
        captures = match.capturesdict()
        print(captures)

get_location("Im at building 3")
```

Output:

```
('Match', <regex.Match object; span=(3, 14), match='at building'>)
at building
{'place': ['at building'], 'location': ['at building']}
```

Note that `location_pattern = 'at|outside\s\w+` is NOT working since `at` is matched everywhere, and `outside` must be followed with a whitespace and word chars. You may fix it the same way: `(at|outside)\s\w+`.

If you put the keywords into a group, the `the captures = match.capturesdict()` will work well (see the output above).

Comment: I removed `MULTILINE`, `VERBOSE` and `DOTALL` modifiers from the demo because the regex does not use any of the affected features.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to only get building and not 'at'?

Comment: @user3667569: See [this demo](http://rextester.com/RRX98021). Wrap the `[A-Za-z]+` part with capturing parentheses and grab its respective `.group(3)` or `.group(4)` (I removed outer numbered capturing group in this example) value.